# How to precisely sample data with frequency of 60Hz?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sampling, data-science, gameobject

Actually, I use the `InvokeRepeating` method to invoke another method every 1/x seconds. The problem is that the precision of the delay between the invoke and the data I got is not good.

How I can precisely sample `transform.position` with a frequency of 60Hz.

Here's my code:

```
public class Recorder : MonoBehaviour {

public float samplingRate = 60f; // sample rate in Hz
public string outputFilePath;

private StreamWriter _sw;

private List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

public void OnEnable()
{

    InvokeRepeating("SampleNow", 0, 1 / samplingRate);
}

public void OnDisable()
{
    _sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(outputFilePath);

    for (int k=0; k< dataList.Count; k++)
    {
        _sw.WriteLine("t {0} x {1} y {2} z {3}",
           dataList[k].time, dataList[k].x, dataList[k].y, dataList[k].z);
    }

    _sw.Close();
    CancelInvoke();
}

public void SampleNow()
{
    dataList.Add(new Data(Time.time, transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
}

public class Data
{
    public float time;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;

    public Data(float time, float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.time = time;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
  }
}
```

So, with this, I can get this kind of result:

```
t 0 x 0 y 0 z 0
t 0.02 x 0.283776 y -0.76 z 0
t 0.04 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.06 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.08 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.09999999 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.12 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.14 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.16 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.18 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.2 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.22 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.24 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.26 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.28 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.3 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.32 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.3338465 x 0.599808 y -0.52 z 0
t 0.3338465 x 0.2918357 y -0.7538424 z 0
t 0.34 x 0.2918357 y -0.7538424 z 0
t 0.3539519 x 0.2918357 y -0.7538424 z 0
t 0.3539519 x 0.6092016 y -0.5125771 z 0
t 0.3705226 x 0.6092016 y -0.5125771 z 0
t 0.3870888 x 0.8340279 y -0.3137283 z 0
t 0.4036556 x 0.9750986 y -0.114934 z 0
t 0.42 x 0.9865224 y 0.09031145 z 0
...
```

As you can see in this result, I can collect duplicate position for different time (t=0.04 to t=0.32)  and worst, I can get duplicate time (t=0.3539519) with different positions (giving an infinite acceleration).

In fact, the gameobject analysed moved with a linear fonction in time, doing a circle in the axis X-Y over 20sec.

So, this code doesn't give me a good precision for a scientific analyze.

What can I do to get more precision with Unity3D?

Comment: Eh...just putting this out there, but you're probably going to want to use something other than Unity if you need precisely calculated/simulated values over defined time steps. As a game engine, it makes many optimizations through approximating things.

Comment: You absolutely cannot.

It's that simple.

Unity has no connection - whatsoever - to that type of engineering .

(Note that "Invoke" just has utterly no connection - AT ALL - to what you're doing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complicated. Although, I wouldn't say that it is *impossbile* to do in Unity. It can be done precisely but not with `InvokeRepeating`.

**You still have two other ways to do this.**

**1**.**`Coroutine`**

If `InvokeRepeating` is too slow, maybe that's because it uses reflection to call the function or maybe the implementation is not perfect.

You may be able to accomplish this by doing a direct function call with a coroutine and waiting with [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) instead of [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) is new in Unity and does not depend on the frame-rate to wait. [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) does.

```
public float samplingRate = 60f; // sample rate in Hz

void OnEnable()
{
    StartCoroutine(startSampling());
}

IEnumerator startSampling()
{
    WaitForSecondsRealtime waitTime = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1f / samplingRate);
    while (true)
    {
        SampleNow();
        yield return waitTime;
    }
}

public void SampleNow()
{
    Debug.Log("Called");
    dataList.Add(new Data(Time.time, transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
}
```

**2**.**`Thread`** (Recommended)

This, I recommended you should use as you will totally avoid any framerate slow down by Unity's main Thread. Do the timer operation in another `Thread`.

The problem with this is that you **won't** be able to use `transform.position.x` or the `Transform` class in another Thread. Unity prevents you from doing so. You will have to execute `dataList.Add(new Data(Time.time, transform.position.x...` in the Main `Thread`. Another option is to store `transform.position` in a global `Vector3` variable then acceess it from another `Thread`.

You **cannot** also use `Time.time` in another `Thread` and will have to get it in the Main `Thread`, then store it in a local variable that will be used in a `Thread` function

You will also have to use the `lock` keyword to make it *Thread-safe*. Note that using the `lock` keyword will slow down your Game a *little* bit. It will remove at-least 2 or 3 frames from your game, but it is required and worth the benefit and protection it provides.

The code below will do everything I just said. The sampling rate is set to 2 times per-sec for testing purposes. You can change chage that to your 60Hz in the `samplingRate` variable, when you think it is working propery.

```
private List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

Thread samplingThread;
const float samplingRate = 2f; // sample rate in Hz

Vector3 posInThread;
float TimetimeInThread;

private System.Object threadLocker = new System.Object();


void OnEnable()
{
    startSampling();
}

void startSampling()
{
    samplingThread = new Thread(OnSamplingData);
    samplingThread.Start();
}

void Update()
{
    lock (threadLocker)
    {
        //Update this values to be used in another Thread
        posInThread = transform.position;
        TimetimeInThread = Time.time;
    }
}

void OnSamplingData()
{
    long oldTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    long currentTime = oldTime;
    const float waitTime = 1f / samplingRate;
    float counter;

    while (true)
    {
        currentTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        counter = (float)TimeSpan.FromTicks(currentTime - oldTime).TotalSeconds;

        if (counter >= waitTime)
        {
            //Debug.Log("counter: " + counter + "  waitTime: " + waitTime);
            oldTime = currentTime; //Store current Time
            SampleNow();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(0); //Make sure Unity does not freeze
    }
}

public void SampleNow()
{
    Debug.Log("Called");
    lock (threadLocker)
    {
        dataList.Add(new Data(TimetimeInThread, posInThread.x, posInThread.y, posInThread.z));
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    if (samplingThread != null && samplingThread.IsAlive)
    {
        samplingThread.Abort();
    }
    samplingThread.Join(); //Wait for Thread to finish then exit
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The coroutine is better. The precision of the call is +- 2ms for a very simple application. This can be enough I think. I still consider using C++ for more precision if needed.

Comment: I am a C++ programmer but I don't know how using C++ will improve the precision. Glad the coroutine version helped you.