# Unity | Command Pattern Playback Timing Difference

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine, architecture, command-pattern

I'm using the Command Pattern to track movement for "replays" later. When I do this, the actions replay correctly, but slower. I have tried both coroutines and `Update()` and the problem persists.

I first have an **Invoker** `PlayerControl` that holds a list of `ICommand`'s.

```
//Properties
private List<ICommand> oldCommands = new List<ICommand>();
private int updateIterationTracker = 0;
```

For every invoked command, I add the command to the list.

```
//If Input moves up, invoke the move up command
if (dirVector.y > 0)
{
    oldCommands.Add(dirUp); //Add the command to the list of commands
    dirUp.Execute();
}
```

At some point a "replay" is triggered and I iterate through the commands in `oldCommands`.

This functionality works. Just as move input does, triggering the command to move executes.

```
private void IterateUpdateOnReplay(){
    if(iteration < oldCommands.Count){
        transform.position = replayStartPosition;
    }
    oldCommands[iteration].Execute();
    iteration++;
}
```

I have done this in a coroutine as well.

The playback may execute the movements in the correct order and the movements may occur, but the time it takes to execute the entire sequence is longer than the time it took at the initial recording. **Playback is longer.**

***Questions:***

1) Is the initial capture

```
oldCommands.Add(dirUp); //Add the command to the list of commands
```

adding too many commands to play back at the correct pace, slowed down by execution times?

2) Is there potentially another issue causing this delay that I am unaware of?

Comment: You need to perform sampling on the game objects you want to store their position then store the data in class.Maybe 30 times per-sec? It depends on how smooth you want it to be. You can then loop over them later on to play them and then delay with the time in the stored class. Start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40732139/3785314).

Comment: Doesn't that go against the point of a command pattern? Instead of storing all the data for the class, you just call the same commands in the same order and the replay should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the entire process and the issue is resolved. In my move commands, I had a command that would clear the movement (which was initially based on velocity, setting the velocity to zero). This occurred each frame as to not allow the velocity to continue movement beyond a button press.

Saving this command was doubling the commands stored in the list causing playback to take longer. When I changed the movement to a position update and remove the clear command, the replay was corrected and playback is normal.